# change icon color on lighting tab

Tags: tab, icon

trying to change the color of an utility icon on a lightning tab but adding a variant does not work. What are the possible ways to change the color of the lightning tab icon?

```
<lightning-tab label='{label}' value={value} end-icon-name='utility:icon' variant='Error'></lightning-tab>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either Styling Hooks or Design Token to change the Tab Icon Color as below.

Styling Hooks

```
.blue-icon{
    --slds-c-icon-color-foreground-default:red;
}
```

Design Token

```
.blue-icon{
    --lwc-colorTextIconDefault:blue;
}
```

HTML

```
<template>   
    <lightning-card>
        <lightning-tabset class="blue-icon">
            <lightning-tab end-icon-name="utility:button_choice" label="Item One"> 
                Content for tab 1 
            </lightning-tab>
        </lightning-tabset>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Comment: Seems that this using this method causes any utility icons within the tab to pickup that colour too :(

Comment: Unfortunately Custom CSS classes doesn't work at `lightning-tab` tag. Here is a known bug for Aura component, I believe this is applied for LWC as well https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000BNEPQA4